# filter on a topological space- how to define filter

Tags: general-topology

So $(X,\tau$) is a topological space. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of closed sets in $X$. Then a $\textit{filter}$, on $\mathcal{C}$, call it $\mathcal{F}$, is a sub collection of these closed sets such that

$(1)$ $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$

$(2)$ closed under intersection, that is, if $C_i,C_j \in \mathcal{F}$, then $C_i \cap C_j \in \mathcal{F}$.

($3)$ closed under supersets?, that is if $C_i \subset C_j$ where $C_i \in \mathcal{F}$ and $C_j \in \mathcal{C}$, then $C_j \in \mathcal{F}$.

My problem says if every filter on $\mathcal{C}$ has non-empty intersection, prove that $(X,\tau)$ is compact.

I'd like how to rigorously define what it means for a filter to have nonempty intersection, so what intersection is nonempty? what is the subscript? where are the elements being pulled from?

so $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$ but I am so lost when it comes to the subscripts here, that is, the subscript of my $\bigcap$. Basically want to know how to formally define a filter on a top space. I have never heard of filters til now. Are they a way of sort of sifting out smaller sets and only including "bigger" sets? And can one put a filter on $\tau$ as well as the closed subsets? What is the purpose of a filter? Feel like once I get a hang on what a filter is I could possibly prove this statement, so I would like to know about this filter business not a solution to my problem I want to still attempt it myself I do not like spoon feeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need any subscripts: by definition

$$\bigcap\mathscr{F}=\{x\in X:\forall F\in\mathscr{F}(x\in F)\}\,.$$

It is simply the intersection of the family $\mathscr{F}$ of sets, the set of points of $X$ that belong to every member of the family $\mathscr{F}$.

If you choose to index $\mathscr{F}$ by some index set $I$, so that $\mathscr{F}=\{F_i:i\in I\}$, then

$$\bigcap\mathscr{F}=\bigcap_{i\in I}F_i\,,$$

but there is generally no need to do so.

Comment: So the phrase "every filter having nonempty intersection" translates to the intersection you defined being non-empty?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Yes, exactly.

Comment: one more question, if I take an arbitrary open cover of $X$ say $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ then is it ok to go ahead and assume then that elements of $\mathcal{C}$ are complements of the $U_\alpha$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Other way around: if $\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ is an open cover of $X$, then $\{X\setminus U_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}\subseteq\mathscr{C}$. In other words, the complements of the sets $U_\alpha$ are all in $\mathscr{C}$, by it’s not necessarily true that every closed set is the complement of some $U_\alpha$.

Comment: true yes you are correct, I cannot go ahead ant suppose that the closed sets are complements since the covering was arbitrarily chosen. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Brian already explained what the intersection means: the set of all points of $X$ that lie in *all* members of the filter $\mathcal{F}$.

If all (closed) filters have non-empty intersection. Then start with an arbitrary cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$. If it has a finite subcover you're done. If not, consider $\mathcal{G}=\{X\setminus U: U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ and consider the smallest filter that contains it...

Comment: so am I going to take the open sets whose complements are elements of the filter?  as the sub cover containing $X$?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame in the second case  we get a contradiction so we conclude that a finite subcover exists

Comment: @HossienSahebjame You take all complements of the members of the open cover .By assumption, their finite intersections are non-empty (or we'd have a finite subcover!) and taking all closed supersets too gets us a filter with empty intersection.